# 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I just created an application on android optimized for the mobile phone. Now as the client asked to optimize for 17inch screen size without building separate apk. I almost implemented with some minor UI changes. But in case of listviews, they need Gridviews. So What I did was I created a separate layout for bigger screen with gridview I used a code to detect the screen size and in activity I used a code to detect the screen size and if it's bigger, then I initialized Gridview and after async task i added to a cardview adapter and set the gridview adapter to cardview adapter.

I switched gridview and listview as:

```
 if(Constants.isScreenLarge(getActivity())) {
            // width > height, better to use Landscape
            mygrid = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.card_gridview);
        } else {
            listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.card_listView);
            listView.addHeaderView(new View(getActivity()));
            listView.addFooterView(new View(getActivity()));
        }
```

Using Restclient helper:

```
 public void fetchTransaction(){
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pd.setMessage("Fetching Transactions..Please Wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
        String fromDate = from.getText().toString();
        String toDate = to.getText().toString();
        //mydb.deleteAllTransactions();
        cardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_card);
        cardArrayAdapter.clear();
        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String userid = prefs.getString("userId","0");
        Log.e("TRANSACTON", Constants.BASE_URL_TRANSACTIONS+"?deviceid="+android_id+"&userid="+userid+"&from="+fromDate+"&to="+toDate);
        RestClientHelper.getInstance().get(Constants.BASE_URL_TRANSACTIONS+"?deviceid="+android_id+"&userid="+userid+"&from="+fromDate+"&to="+toDate, new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                pd.dismiss();
                try{
                    mydb.deleteAllTransactions();
                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray posts = result.optJSONArray("result");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                            String id = post.optString("id");
                            String heading = post.optString("heading");
                            String description = post.optString("description");
                            String amount = post.optString("amount");
                            String imageurl = post.optString("imageurl");
                            String credit = post.optString("credit");
                            String date = post.optString("date");
                            String type = post.optString("type");
                        String service = post.optString("service");
                        String cost = post.optString("cost");
                        String balance = post.optString("balance");
                        String amountinfo = post.optString("amountinfo");
                            Log.e("ENTERING TO DB","DATA"+i);
                            Card card = new Card(heading, description,amount,date,credit,imageurl,cost,balance,amountinfo,id,service);
                            cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
                            //mydb.addTransactionContact(new TransactionData(heading, description, amount, imageurl,credit,type,date));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
                finally {
                    //showTransaction();
                    rl = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.noItems);
                    rl.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    if(Constants.isScreenLarge(getActivity())) {
                        // width > height, better to use Landscape
                        mygrid.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
                    } else {
                        listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
                    }
                    cardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                SnackbarManager.show(Snackbar.with(getActivity()) // context
                        .text("An Error occured.. Try after sometime"));
                textView2.setText("Some Error Ocurred");
                rl = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.noItems);
                rl.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
```

My CardArrayAdapter code is:

```
public class CardArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
    private static final String TAG = "CardArrayAdapter";
    private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private Context mContext;
    DatabaseUserTable mydb;
    PreferenceHelper prefs;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    static class CardViewHolder {
        TextView line1;
        TextView line2;
        ImageView cimageView;
        TextView amount;
        TextView credit;
        TextView date;

        TextView cost;
        TextView balance;
        TextView amountinfo;

        TextView costinfo;
        TextView balanceinfo;

    }

    public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.mContext = context;
        mydb = new DatabaseUserTable(this.mContext);
        prefs = new PreferenceHelper(this.mContext);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this.mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Card object) {
        cardList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.cardList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Card getItem(int index) {
        return this.cardList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        CardViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new CardViewHolder();
            viewHolder.line1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line1);
            viewHolder.line2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line2);

            viewHolder.amount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date);
            viewHolder.credit = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.credit);
            viewHolder.cimageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageId);


            viewHolder.cost = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cost);
            viewHolder.balance = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.balance);
            viewHolder.amountinfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amountinfo);
            viewHolder.costinfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.costinfo);
            viewHolder.balanceinfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.balanceinfo);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (CardViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Card card = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.line1.setText(card.getLine1());
        viewHolder.line1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.line2.setText(card.getLine2());
        viewHolder.line2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

        viewHolder.amount.setText(card.getAmount());
        viewHolder.amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.date.setText(card.getDate());
        viewHolder.date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

        viewHolder.credit.setText(card.getCredit());
        viewHolder.credit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.cost.setText(card.getCost());
        viewHolder.cost.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.balance.setText(card.getBalance());
        viewHolder.balance.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.amountinfo.setText(card.getAmountinfo());
        viewHolder.amountinfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.costinfo.setText("Cost");
        viewHolder.costinfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.balanceinfo.setText("Balance");
        viewHolder.balanceinfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        final String salesid = card.getSalesid();
        final String servicename = card.getServiceName();
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               Log.e("TRANSACTIONS SERVICENAM",servicename);
                if(servicename.equals("VOUCHER")) {

                    alertBox(v,salesid);
                }

                else if(servicename.equals("WALLET")) {
                    SnackbarManager.show(Snackbar.with(v.getRootView().getContext()) // context
                            .text("No Reprinting available for this transaction"));
                }
                else if(servicename.equals("ELECTRICITY")) {
                    errorAlert(v,"Printing not yet supported");
                    //alertBoxElectricity(v,salesid);
                }
                else if(servicename.equals("MONEY TRANSFER")) {
                    //errorAlert(v,"Printing not yet supported");
                    alertBoxMoney(v,salesid);
                }
                else{
                    alertBoxOther(v,salesid);
                }
                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), amountinfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*SnackbarManager.show(Snackbar.with(this) // context
                        .text(amountinfo));*/
            }
        });
        Log.e("card.getLine1()",card.getLine1());
        Log.e("TRASACTION URL",Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE+card.getUrl());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE+card.getUrl()).fit().placeholder(R.drawable.mobeeloadicon).error(R.drawable.mobeeloadicon).into(viewHolder.cimageView);
        return row;
    }
```

But I got the error as:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

How can I change CardArrayAdapter as GridViewAdapter preserving all the Card data. Any Help please

**UPDATE**

I got this right. It was a silly mistake. I was populating the wrong layout.

Comment: remove line 
        cardArrayAdapter.clear();

Comment: @YoLo. No still same error

Comment: check your if and else statements are the satisfying the criteria or not

Comment: @YoLo. Yes, it does. I Logged and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I got this, My Mistake. I was calling the wrong layout.

Comment: good to hear actually i was going to ask for xml